# Proof regarding size and dimension of linear codes

Tags: self-learning, coding-theory, information-theory

**The problem is stated as follows:**

Let **C** be a binary linear code of length **n**, dimension **k** and distance **d** and assume that **C** contains at least one element of odd weight.

Let **C'** be the subset of **C** consisting of all code words of even weight. Show that **C'** is a linear code of length **n**, dimension **k −1** and distance **d'** where **d' > d** if d is odd and **d'= d** if d is even

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: This is basic stuff from linear algebra. The code $C'$ is the kernel of the linear function that calculates the sum of the components of a codeword. That function is onto, iff there exists a word of an odd weight, and rank-nullity will give you the dimension. The deductions about the minimum distance are very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Prof. Lahtonen's comment settles it (as usual!), but I will try to elaborate a bit. If the code $\mathcal{C}$ has at least $1$ odd weight codeword, it is an independent vector as no $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear combination of the remaining even codewords can generate it. Hence the dimension of $\mathcal{C'}$ is $k -1$.

The distance is easy: if $d$ is odd, that's the weight of an odd codeword, and so $d'> d$; the other case follows.

Comment: Can you give an example to show that the dimension of $\mathcal C^\prime$ can be _strictly_ smaller than $k-1$?

Comment: Also, if there exist at least one odd weight codeword, then exactly one half of the codewords will have an odd weight. Namely those in a coset of $C'$.

Comment: Many thanks to Prof. Sarwate and Prof. Lahtonen for your comments. I see I didn't think it through. I will modify my post accordingly.